# ECDSA host fingerprint changes if the host is already known

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, known-hosts, fingerprint

I'm using a web hosting service that offers both FTP and SSH access, but for SSH they only allow authentication via SSH keys. I've generated myself SSH keys using `ssh-keygen`, imported them into my Ubuntu system using `ssh-add`, and uploaded the key to my hosting service's web control panel. My `~/.ssh/config` file contains this:

```
Host myhostname
Hostname ssh.myhostname.com
User myhostname
PubKeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/aaronfranke/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The host name and username are the same, but I've replaced the name with "myhostname" for all the config/terminal snips. The first time I connect in the terminal, I get permission denied (publickey):

```
$ ssh myhostname
The authenticity of host 'ssh.myhostname.com (23.217.138.110)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:6MJJtqKhTdHXF2yzH/0UqGN2o4RZ2PDEp2ttdA/IJR8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ssh.myhostname.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
myhostname@ssh.myhostname.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Immediately afterwards, if I try to reconnect, I get an error that the ECDSA host key has changed:

```
$ ssh myhostname
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The ECDSA host key for ssh.myhostname.com has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 23.202.231.169
is unchanged. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
Offending key for IP in /home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "23.202.231.169"
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:HnzBy7BAfkMCT4uIcdLrpoWiOrnhHhN8k7XMbbB2Epk.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts:3
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "ssh.myhostname.com"
ECDSA host key for ssh.myhostname.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I can do as suggested and remove the key from the list of known hosts...

```
$ ssh-keygen -f "/home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "ssh.myhostname.com"
# Host ssh.myhostname.com found: line 3
/home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts.old
```

...but if I reconnect, I get the same message above as the first time I connect, and then again the same message about the host key changing. The exact same thing happens if I run `rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

What's weird is that these messages are the **exact** same. Every time, if the host is not in my `known_hosts` file, the server fingerprint is `SHA256:6MJJtqKhTdHXF2yzH/0UqGN2o4RZ2PDEp2ttdA/IJR8`, and every time the host is known, the server fingerprint is `SHA256:HnzBy7BAfkMCT4uIcdLrpoWiOrnhHhN8k7XMbbB2Epk`

Why would the fingerprint change depending on if the host is known or not? How can I stop the fingerprint from changing? Is there something wrong with my client or with the server?

Is there a way that I can manually insert the host fingerprint provided by the 2nd connect attempt into my `known_hosts` file? Is there a way I can authorize both fingerprints?

Comment: Please show Your SSH verbose output. I doubt that the fingerprint depends on whether You have the host in in Your known hosts file. I assume You are targeted to a round robin DNS or such You have a very special SSH config that is causing different target IPs (and hosts) depending on whether the host is known. You can see two different IP addresses in the messages thus it will be two different servers You connect to each with it's own host key. Everything right that far.

Comment: @EOhm https://pastebin.com/brpvynLL

Comment: So it's showing nothing suspicious at Level 1 verbose, only what I think. Maybe You can confirm with some queries to DNS. Or just try whether adding the host key for both IP's help? `ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa ssh.myhostname.net,23.202.231.169 >> /home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts; ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa ssh.myhostname.net,23.217.138.110 >> /home/aaronfranke/.ssh/known_hosts`